# My code compiled, but won't run in the terminal

Tags: java

I'm trying to run this in the terminal and it compiles, creates the .class files, but won't run. The code runs and executes as planned in Netbeans (in Windows), but won't run in the terminal for my VirtualBox. The error that I'm getting is that it cannot find the main class.

```
package stackdemo;

public class ArrayStackDemo {

    //Demo
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StackInt demoStack = new StackInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < demoStack.size(); i++) {
            demoStack.push(i);
            System.out.println(demoStack.pop());
        }
    }
}

package stackdemo;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class StackInt {
    //Instance variables
    private int[] numberStack;
    int topOfStack = -1; //Empty stack
    private int capacity;
    private final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;

    //Default constructer
    public StackInt() {
        capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        numberStack = new int[capacity];
    }

    //Size method
    public int size() {
        return capacity;
    }

    //Empty method
    public boolean empty() {
        if (topOfStack == -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Push method
    public int push(int obj) {
        if (topOfStack == numberStack.length - 1) {
            reallocate();
        }
        topOfStack++;
        numberStack[topOfStack] = obj;
        return obj;
    }

    //Reallocate method
    public void reallocate() {
        capacity = 2 * capacity;
        numberStack = Arrays.copyOf(numberStack, capacity);
    }

    //Pop method    
    public int pop() {
        if (empty()) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        return numberStack[topOfStack--];
    }

    //Peek method
    public int peek() {
        if (empty()) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        return numberStack[topOfStack];
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe silly, but are you trying to run `ArrayStackDemo ` or `StackInt `?

Comment: And how are you starting the application? Give us the command you're executing, tell us which directory you're in, and where are the class files.

Comment: remove the package stackdemo; in both coding.

Comment: @PradeepSimha ArrayStackDemo

Comment: @Sathesh: that's a very very bad advice to give.

Comment: @JBNizet java ArrayStackDemo

Comment: "The error that I'm getting is that it cannot find the main class" this means you're starting it wrong, it's not related to your code. Let us know how you try to run it.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm in the documents directory james@virtual-pc:~/Documents$, the class files are in the same place. I compiled using javac *.java

Comment: @eis I'm trying to start it by typing java ArrayStackDemo

Comment: @Nostradonis try `java -classpath . stackdemo.ArrayStackDemo`

Comment: your ArrayStackDemo.class is compiled to the directory `stackdemo` correct?

Comment: @MaxFichtelmann There is no stackdemo directory. That's the package it's in when I use Netbeans. Should I create one and put everything in there? I'm trying to depend less on IDEs

Comment: packages should match directories in the file system.

Comment: @eis so in my documents folder I should have stackdemo.package and store the class files and source code in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you create a directory structure like this:

```
src/
  stackdemo/
    ArrayStackDemo.java
    StackInt.java
bin/
```

then you run the compiler to generate the class files

```
javac -s src -d bin src/stackdemo/*.java
```

which creates the .class files at the proper location in the `bin` directory

```
bin/
  stackdemo/
    ArrayStackDemo.class
    StackInt.class
```

you can then execute the main class using the full qualified classname (`<package>.<classname>`)

```
java -cp bin stackdemo.ArrayStackDemo
```

This may appear cumbersome - but build tools have been created to deal with this. In the java world the common tool is [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), which brings dependency management on top of the plain compiling stuff (and more). Many IDE's support these kinds of projects and to be able to build independently of the IDE I would strongly recommend it.

Comment: Can you tell me what -s and -d do? I'm guessing -cp compiles and runs?

Comment: `java -help`, `java -help` explain these parameters - in short `-s` specifies the sourcepath (where the sources lie), `-d` specifies the destination path (where the .class files should be put). `-cp` is the classpath option.

Comment: a could be needed, when compiling multiple files with dependencies on each other... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the folder that contains the folder named `stackdemo`:

```
java -cp . stackdemo.ArrayStackDemo
```

If you are compiling and then creating a jar file first make sure that the jar file has a manifest before you run `java -jar <yourjar>`. The manifest should be called `META_INF/MANIFEST.MF` inside the jar. It is a plain text file that contains at least the line `Main-Class: stackdemo.ArrayStackDemo`.